# css error en chrome : 'Unknown property name'

Tags: html, css

I want to modify the slider but I get this error:

```
Unknown property name
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using chrome and my os is windows 7.

[image]

```
<head>
<body>
   <div class="gene_controller width" data-original_value="0" data-name="width">
      <p class="gene_name">width</p>
      <div class="gene_slider">
         <div class="gene_input_row"><img class="undo invisible" src="/image/reset.png" style="padding:1px;"><input class="number_input slider-input" type="number" value="0" step="0.1"><img class="x" src="icons/scroll.svg"></div>
         <div class="slider"><input type="range" min="-2" max="2" step="any" value="0"></div>
      </div>
    <!--document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0].children[0].min
    esto es un comentario en html
    -->
<style>

input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 21px;
        width: 11px;
        background: svg-load(".\icons\indicator-horizontal.svg");
        transform: translateY(-8px);
    }
    &::-moz-range-thumb {
        height: 41px;
        width: 11px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: svg-load(".\icons\indicator-horizontal.svg");
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
    &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: black;
        border-right: 1px solid grey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        box-shadow: 1px 0 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white, 0 1px 0 white, -1px 0 0 darkgrey, -1px -1px 0 darkgrey,
            0 -1px 0 darkgrey, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px -1px darkgrey;
    }
    &::-moz-range-track {
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: black;
        border-right: 1px solid grey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        box-shadow: 1px 0 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white, 0 1px 0 white, -1px 0 0 darkgrey, -1px -1px 0 darkgrey,
            0 -1px 0 darkgrey, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px -1px darkgrey;
    }
}
</style>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path is not correct, use this format:

`./icons/indicator-horizontal.svg`

for more examples check this link:

`https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using  `background: svg-load(".\icons\indicator-horizontal.svg");` property wrongly.

Simply try with  `background: url(".\icons\indicator-horizontal.svg");` everywhere you using `background` property.

Make sure you use the correct url relative path w.r.t your CSS file.

Answer (score -2):

convert your scss to css

```css
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance:none;width:100%;background:transparent
}
input[type="range"]:focus{
    outline:none
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    height:21px;
    width:11px;
    background:svg-load(".iconsindicator-horizontal.svg");
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-8px);
    transform:translateY(-8px)}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb{
    height:41px;
    width:11px;
    border:0;
    border-radius:0;
    background:svg-load(".iconsindicator-horizontal.svg");
    transform:translateY(2px)}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:black;
    border-right:1px solid grey;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    box-shadow:1px 0 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white, 0 1px 0 white, -1px 0 0 darkgrey, -1px -1px 0 darkgrey, 0 -1px 0 darkgrey, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px -1px darkgrey
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track{
    width:100%;
    height:2px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:black;
    border-right:1px solid grey;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    box-shadow:1px 0 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white, 0 1px 0 white, -1px 0 0 darkgrey, -1px -1px 0 darkgrey, 0 -1px 0 darkgrey, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px -1px darkgrey
}
```

```html
   <div class="gene_controller width" data-original_value="0" data-name="width">
      <p class="gene_name">width</p>
      <div class="gene_slider">
         <div class="gene_input_row"><img class="undo invisible" src="/image/reset.png" style="padding:1px;"><input class="number_input slider-input" type="number" value="0" step="0.1"><img class="x" src="icons/scroll.svg"></div>
         <div class="slider"><input type="range" min="-2" max="2" step="any" value="0"></div>
      </div>
    <!--document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0].children[0].min
    esto es un comentario en html
    -->

   </div>
```